# Tow centralized colomns GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I've created a gridlayout to put 4 images inside it and heres the xml :

```
 <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android: layout_height="238dp"
    android:columnCount="1"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    tools:ignore="NewApi" >

    <ImageView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
 

  </GridLayout>
```

So they've appeard like this :

[image]

and what i actually want is somthing like this :

[image]

And i don't want to use dp margin or padding because of the differences between devices resolutions.

So, How can i centralized those two colomns considering responsive design ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using GridLayout I would suggest you do the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgView3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```